# Comparing variance in random effects: crossed ranom effects or different models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am interested in making sure that a predictor I include into a regression actually explains the type of variance it should. To be more specific: in an experiment in which a number of people sees a number of images each (so every image is seen by every participant once), I expect the picture category to explain variance between individual pictures but not participants. Thus I define a null model:

*Null Model*
`dv ~ 1 + (1 | person) + (1| image)`

and compare it to a model with the predictor

*Meaningful Model*
`dv ~ 1 + image_category + (1 | person) + (1| image)`

in `brms`. Now, both models provide an estimate of the standard deviation for each "random intercept". The standard deviation of the random intercept for images should be much smaller in the second model since much of the differences between the individual images is actually due to categorical differences between them.

**So here is the question:** Is the way I am calculating these standard deviations correct as specified above? Or should I rather have two models in each step that look like this:

*Null Models*

`dv ~ 1 + person + (1| image)`  for the sd(random intercept between images)

`dv ~ 1 + image + (1 | person)`  for the sd(random intercept between persons)

*Meaningful Models*

`dv ~ 1 + image_category + person + (1| image)`  for the sd(random intercept between images)

`dv ~ 1 + image_category + image + (1 | person)`  for the sd(random intercept between persons)

When I calculate the models with both "random effects" in one model, the models run fine. However in the lower case with a seperate model for each "random effect", the calculation in `lme4` throws singularity-warnings (I suspect this has to do with the fact that I have one observation for each participant/image combination). Bayesian models don't have this problem. But their chains either don't converge or they take forever to run when their sampling parameters are set to make them converge.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The crossed random effects models appear to be correct for your intended use. That is, you want to know how much variability in `dv` due to differences among `image` (i.e., random intercept variance) is explained by `image_category`. From your *Null Model* to your *Meaningful Model* (first two models), if `image_category` varies only across `image` and it is a significant predictor of `dv`, then you should see some reduction in the variance of `image` and not in `person`.

You could also use a fixed effects approach, in which dummy coded predictors are used for each level of the clustering variable (i.e., person or image) to control for the influence of clustering on the outcome. However, the fixed effects approach does not allow you to determine the reduction in variance in `image` that is due to `image_category`, so this may not be an option. Nevertheless, in `lme4` and `brms`, you can insert the clustering variable as a predictor (as you've done in the last four models) but as a "factor" class, and both packages know to parse the factor variable as if each level is a separate dummy-coded predictor. If you've done it correctly, you should see $m - 1$ (where $m$ is the number of clusters) cluster-related predictors with a model intercept or $m$ cluster-related predictors without a model intercept. My guess of why your last two models are breaking down is that you have not turned `image` or `person` into factor variables. If that's so, both `lme4` and `brms` are treating each clustering variable as a single predictor rather than $m-1$ or $m$ dummy-coded predictors.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I made sure that the predictors are factors and the models still take very long to run and/or don't converge... I'll post an answer in which I run the models for simulated data. All three cases return similar values, to I think there is no difference between the approaches... What do you think?

Comment: I should have mentioned this: including fixed effects for `person` will not allow you to estimate the effect of `image_category` on the DV. (Here I assume that `image_category` varies over `image` but not `person`.) This is because `image_category` is perfectly collinear with the fixed effects for `person`. Order your data by `person` and you will see that there is no variation of `image_category` across `person`. This also occurs in the simulated data below, where the first model is rank-deficient b/c you include the (within-person) predictor with fixed effects for items. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Scinilla for your answer! I used a simulation of data (from [here](https://debruine.github.io/lmem_sim/index.html)) and tried all three models, and all return similar estimates for the standard deviations. Based on this, I guess there is no difference between the two approaches but if anyone thinks there is, I am happy for suggestions!

```
# data simulation from https://debruine.github.io/lmem_sim/index.html
# load required packages
library("lme4")        # model specification / estimation
library("afex")        # anova and deriving p-values from lmer
library("broom.mixed") # extracting data from model fits 
library("faux")        # data simulation
# NOTE: to install the 'faux' package, use:
# devtools::install_github("debruine/faux")
library("tidyverse")   # data wrangling and visualisation
library("brms")
set.seed(147)


#  data simulation function -----
my_sim_data <- function(
  nsubj  = 100, # number of subjects
  nitem  = c(ingroup = 25, outgroup = 25),  # number of items
  b0     = 800, # grand mean
  b1     =  50, # effect of category
  I0i_sd =  80, # by-item random intercept sd
  S0s_sd = 100, # by-subject random intercept sd
  S1s_sd =  40, # by-subject random slope sd
  scor   = 0.2, # correlation between intercept and slope
  err_sd = 200){  # residual (standard deviation)

  # simulate items
  items <- faux::sim_design(
    between = list(category = c("ingroup", "outgroup")),
    n = nitem,
    sd = I0i_sd,
    dv = "I0i",
    id = "item_id",
    plot = FALSE    
  )

  # effect code category
  items$cat <- recode(items$category, "ingroup" = -0.5, "outgroup" =     0.5)

  # simulate subjects
  subjects <- faux::sim_design(
    within = list(effect = c(S0s = "By-subject random intercepts", 
                         S1s = "By-subject random slopes")), 
    n = nsubj,
    sd = c(S0s_sd, S1s_sd), 
    r = scor,
    id = "subj_id",
    plot = FALSE
  )

  # simulate trials
  dat_sim <- crossing(subj_id = subjects$subj_id,
                      item_id = items$item_id) %>%
    inner_join(subjects, "subj_id") %>%
    inner_join(items, "item_id") %>%
    mutate(err = rnorm(nrow(.), mean = 0, sd = err_sd)) %>%
    mutate(RT = b0 + I0i + S0s + (b1 + S1s) * cat + err) %>%
    select(subj_id, item_id, category, cat, RT)

  dat_sim
}

# generate the data -----

data <- my_sim_data()
data <- data %>%
  mutate(item_id = factor(item_id), # make sure, the predictors are     factors
         subj_id = factor(subj_id))

is.factor(data$subj_id)

# lme4 fits -----
fitvp <- lmer(RT ~ 1  + cat +item_id + (1 | subj_id),
          data = data, REML = TRUE)

fitItem <- lmer(RT ~ 1  + cat +subj_id + (1 | item_id),
            data = data, REML = TRUE)

fitboth <- lmer(RT ~ 1  + cat +(1| subj_id) + (1 | item_id),
            data = data, REML = TRUE)

summary(fitvp, corr = FALSE)
summary(fitItem, corr = FALSE)
summary(fitboth, corr = FALSE)

# brms fits ----

Bfitvp <- brm(RT ~ 1  + cat +item_id + (1 | subj_id),
          data = data, 
          inits = 0,
          cores = parallel::detectCores(), 
          control = list(max_treedepth = 11))

BfitItem <- brm(RT ~ 1  + cat +subj_id + (1 | item_id),
            data = data, 
            inits = 0,
            cores = parallel::detectCores(), 
            control = list(max_treedepth = 11))

Bfitboth <- brm(RT ~ 1  + cat +(1| subj_id) + (1 | item_id),
            data = data, 
            inits = 0,
            cores = parallel::detectCores(), 
            control = list(max_treedepth = 11))

subjOnlyPlot <- stanplot(Bfitvp, pars = "sd_sub") + xlim(60,130) + theme_bw()
itemOnlyPlot <- stanplot(BfitItem, pars = "sd_item") + xlim(60,130) + theme_bw()
bothPlot <- stanplot(Bfitboth, pars = c("sd_sub", "sd_item")) + xlim(60,130) + theme_bw()

cowplot::plot_grid(subjOnlyPlot, itemOnlyPlot, bothPlot,
               nrow = 3,
               ncol = 1, 
               labels = c("A", "B", "C"))
```